# Can I easily limit which files a user can download from an Amazon S3 server?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, heroku, amazon-s3

I have tried looking for an answer to this but I think I am perhaps using the wrong terminology so I figure I will give this a shot.

I have a Rails app where a company can have an account with multiple users each with various permissions etc.  Part of the system will be the ability to upload files and I am looking at S3 for storage.  What I want is the ability to say that users from Company A can only download the files associated with that company?

I get the impression I can't unless I restrict the downloads to my deployment servers IP range (which will be Heroku) and then feed the files through a controller and a send_file() call.  This would work but then I am reading data from S3 to Heroku then back to the user vs. direct from S3 to the user.

If I went with the send_file method can I close off my S3 server to the outside world and have my Heroku app send the file direct?

A less secure idea I had was to create a unique slug for each file and store it under that name to prevent random guessing of files i.e. `http://mys3server/W4YIU5YIU6YIBKKD.jpg` etc. This would be quick and dirty but not 100% secure.

Answer (score 0):

Amazon S3 Buckets support policies for granting or denying access based on different conditions. You could probably use those to protect your files from different user groups. Have a look at the [policy documentation](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/AccessPolicyLanguage_ElementDescriptions.html) to get an idea what is possible. After that you can switch over to the [AWS policy generator](http://awspolicygen.s3.amazonaws.com/policygen.html) to generate a valid policy depending on your needs.

Comment: It looks pretty robust but at the end of the day if my bucket is open via http I can't really limit who can view images / download files with out making separate buckets and adding authentication.  If my Heroku app links to an external S3 URL any user could copy and paste that from outside the app or even share that with another person.  When S3 or any other web server serves a file you can't restrict delivery from a direct link vs a link embedded in HTML of a site can you?

Comment: It seems you can limit the IP range that is allowed to download your file. You can use this to let only your server (or network) download files: http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/AccessPolicyLanguage_ElementDescriptions.html#Conditions_IPAddress

Comment: I thought about that but then I have to feed all files through my Heroku app.  After some further digging I am going to probably go with  a combination of the slugs and the expiring URL options.